# Song Application - SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context

Tags: actionscript-3

When I click on the respective button for each song it comes up with the following error.

SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.

None of the songs play.

I have checked the path to the MP3s folder but I cant find what I have done wrong.

```
var songList:Array=new Array("Faster","Floofin","Healing Invitation","Leave The Light On","Lift Me Up","Looking Up","Shelter","Sparkles On Her Dress","Squirrel Map","TapTouch","Vancouver Transit","What_");

song1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song12.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);

for (var i = 0; i < songList.length; i++){
var str:String = songList[i] as String;
str = str.replace(".mp3","");
var clip = this["song"+(i+1)].title;
clip.text = str;
}
function chooseSong(e:MouseEvent):void{
    switch(e.currentTarget.name){
    case "song1":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[0] as String;
        break;
    case "song2":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[1] as String;
        break;
    case "song3":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[2] as String;
        break;
    case "song4":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[3] as String;
        break;
    case "song5":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[4] as String;
        break;
    case "song6":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[5] as String;
        break;
    case "song7":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[6] as String;
        break;
    case "song8":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[7] as String;
        break;
    case "song9":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[8] as String;
        break;
    case "song10":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[9] as String;
        break;
    case "song11":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[10] as String;
        break;
    case "song12":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[11] as String;
        break;

}
if(snd != null){
    channel.stop();
}
snd = new Sound();
snd.load(new URLRequest(currSong));

channel = new SoundChannel;
trans = new SoundTransform(currVol, currPan);
channel = snd.play();
channel.soundTransform = trans;
nowPlaying.visible = true;

snd.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
}
```

I am using Action Script 3 in CS5.5

EDIT: I have looked at answer to similar questions but without any luck

Thanks

Comment: You could add an event listener for IOErrorEvent.IO_Error on snd. In the listener, you could trace the event (event.text) and that might give you more information regarding the error you have.

Comment: @CristinaGeorgescu Ok could you please give me the code I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading external resources it's best to also add event listeners for error events, so if something goes wrong you have some idea why. Even though you checked the path to your mp3s, it still might be wrong. To really check that your path is correct, you need an IO_Error event listener added like this:

```
snd = new Sound();
snd.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoError);

snd.load(new URLRequest(currSong));

function onIoError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
   trace("io Error: " + evt.text);
}
```

There is also an example in the AS3 Docs about the events you can listen to on a Sound object. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#includeExamplesSummary